# Component with picklist after clicking icon

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I'm new to Lightning Components development and I'm learning it from the scratch. I hope you'll help me or advise me :)

My goal is to make a custom component. Something like this:

[image]

So far I have only text input field with an svg icon on the left. I don't have idea how to make some picklist showing any content that appears after clicking my svg icon with scrollable attribute. Which technology i should use? Or maybe there are existing components with such a functionality?

I do very want to learn lightning components, but I find it very difficult and I'dont have a clue how to connect things properly.

Best regards! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Easiest approach here would be use to the newly introduced **lightning:menuItem** tag from winter 17. [Reference for lightning:menuItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_menuItem.htm). This component makes use of the menu styles from lightning design system library. Furthermore this component has an attribute for the icon as well. [Menu Styles from Lightning Design System Library](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/)

So we should be able to make use of all the [icons from lightning design system library](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/icons) as per our convenience. However do bear in mind that this tag is under **Beta** so you might want to analyze the integrity before you ship it to production.

[image: Sample Menu Item]

Kindly note that using **lightning:menuButton and lightning:menuItem** has some restrictions such as

- Icons will appear only on the right side
- lightning:buttons only take utiltu icons, you will not be able to use custom icons and standard action icons.

Other approach will be to use to the mark-up from lightning design system Menu's to implement this requirement. This will use aura:html and when you click on the icon, use an event handler to toggle the focus of the menu item and the component should work just fine.

[image: Using Lightning Design System]

For toggling the menu on-click, we just have to toggle the class **"slds-is-open"** in the event handler as follows

[image: Controllerjs]

This should work but you might have to add some custom styling to make the elements sit as per your expectation.